# Provisioning a Databricks workspace with Terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

I am trying to create a Databricks workspace by using Terraform on Azure. I use a service principal doing that with this provider configuration:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.sub_id
  client_id = var.client_id
  client_secret = var.client_secret
  tenant_id = var.tenant_id
}
```

With this configuration I can create an `azurerm_databricks_workspace` resource without any problems.

The next step in my workflow is to configure this workspace by creating a `databricks_workspace_conf` resource and passing a `custom_config` to it to disable personal access tokens.

So the basic structure of the Terraform is below:

```
# provider configuration
provider "azurerm" { ... }

resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" { ... }

resource "databricks_workspace_conf" {
 custom_config = { ... }
}
```

What happens is that after creating the workspace, Terraform fails with the error `cannot create workspace conf: authentication is not configured for provider` pointing to the `databricks_workspace_conf` configuration.

So I thought it might be failing because the workspace is not fully functional yet so I moved the `databricks_workspace_conf` into its own module and explicitly pass a provider configuration to it.

After the workspace is created I define another provider like below and pass it to the configuration module:

```
provider "databricks" {
  alias = "dbricks"
  host = "workspace_url output from the workspace resource"
}

module "config" {
  source = "./config"
  providers = {
    databricks = databricks.dbricks
  }
}
```

This configuration fails with the error: `cannot create workspace conf: cannot configure. azure-cli auth..... Please run az login to setup account`

So this makes me think that no matter how I pass the provider configuration, the resource always tries to authenticate with azure-cli which I don't really want.

I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: I'm kind of lost here. Is the Databricks part modularized or Azure or both?

Comment: Only the workspace_conf is modularized. I don't have any other modules. The modularization was something I tried as a workaround, it's not my main goal to use modules. The main issue is that I can't create a config resource after I create a workspace because of the authentication problem.

Comment: Ok, so in order to configure the Databricks provider you need to have a workspace configuration first?

Comment: Yes, you create a workspace first by using `azurerm_databricks_workspace` then continue adding stuff by using the `databricks_` provider.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/unity-catalog-azure#provider-initialization?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Terraform tries to parallelize creation of the resources, so it's trying to create `workspace_conf` before workspace is created and URL of the workspace is known. The workaround for that is to put explicit `depends_on` into your module that, like this (this is described in the Databricks Terraform provider's [troubleshooting guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/troubleshooting#data-resources-and-authentication-is-not-configured-errors)):

```
resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "this" { ... }

provider "databricks" {
  alias = "dbricks"
  host = azurerm_databricks_workspace.this.workspace_url
}

module "config" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_databricks_workspace.this]
  source = "./config"
  providers = {
    databricks = databricks.dbricks
  }
}
```

Unfortunately you can't put `depends_on` into the `provider` block, so you need to have it on all Databricks resources...